# Insert/Update many to many with Generic Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository, code-first

I have problem with insert and update by Generic Repository, in generic insert or update it hasnot problem but in many to many relation i am getting error at insert :

**An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

update:

**The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.**

my codes are

*Interface*

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>:IDisposable
    {
 void Insert(TEntity entity);
 void Update(TEntity entity);
}
```

*Generic class*

```
  public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
            {
                private ApplicationDbContext context=null;
                private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet=null;
                public GenericRepository()
                {
                    this.context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
                }
                public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
                {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
                }

                public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
                {
Error is here--->  this.context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
                   // dbSet.Add(entity);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
                {
Error is here--->   dbSet.Attach(entity);
                    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

        }
```

*and control codes are*

```
        private IGenericRepository<Blog> _Repository = null;
        private IGenericRepository<BlogTag> _RepositoryTag = null;
        private IGenericRepository<BlogCategory> _RepositoryCategory = null;

        public BlogsController()
        {

            this._Repository = new GenericRepository<Blog>(new DbContext());
            this._RepositoryTag = new GenericRepository<BlogTag>(new DbContext());
            this._RepositoryCategory = new GenericRepository<BlogCategory>(new DbContext());
        }

     public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "BlogID,BlogTitle,BlogContent,VisitCount,Preview")] Blog blog
                ,string[] SelectedTags,string[] SelectedCategories, HttpPostedFileBase files)
            {

                if (SelectedTags != null)
                {
                    blog.BlogTags = new List<BlogTag>();
                    foreach (var tag in SelectedTags)
                    {
                        var tagToAdd = _RepositoryTag.GetById(int.Parse(tag));
                        blog.BlogTags.Add(tagToAdd);
                    }
                }
                if (SelectedCategories != null)
                {
                    blog.BlogCategories = new List<BlogCategory>();
                    foreach (var cat in SelectedCategories)
                    {
                        var catToAdd = _RepositoryCategory.GetById(int.Parse(cat));
                        blog.BlogCategories.Add(catToAdd);
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    blog.DateTimeInsert = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    blog.DateTimeModify = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    blog.ImagePath= files != null ? Path.GetFileName(files.FileName) : "";
                    blog.BlogContent = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(blog.BlogContent);

                    _Repository.Insert(blog);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.BlogTags = new SelectList(_RepositoryTag.Get(), "BlogTagID", "TagName");
                ViewBag.BlogCategories = new SelectList(_RepositoryCategory.Get(), "BlogCategoryID", "CategoriesName");

                return View(blog);
            }


            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "BlogID,BlogTitle,BlogContent,VisitCount,Preview")] Blog blog
               , string[] SelectedTags, string[] SelectedCategories, HttpPostedFileBase files)
            {

                if (Request["BlogID"] == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                int id = int.Parse(Request["BlogID"].ToString());
                var blogsToUpdate =  _Repository.Query(i => i.BlogID == id, null).Include(t => t.BlogTags).Include(t => t.BlogCategories).Single();

                if (TryUpdateModel(blogsToUpdate, "",
                   new string[] { "BlogID", "BlogTitle", "BlogContent", "VisitCount","Preview" }))
                {
                    try
                    {


                        UpdateInstructorCourses(SelectedTags, SelectedCategories, blogsToUpdate);

                        blogsToUpdate.DateTimeModify = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        blogsToUpdate.DateTimeInsert = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        blogsToUpdate.BlogContent = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(blogsToUpdate.BlogContent);

                        await _Repository.UpdateAsync(blogsToUpdate,  d => d.BlogTitle, d => d.VisitCount, d => d.BlogContent, d => d.ImagePath);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
                    {
                        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                    }
                }
                AssignedDDLCHKBoxValues(blogsToUpdate);
                return View(blogsToUpdate);
            }

            private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] SelectedTags, string[] SelectedCategories, Blog blogsToUpdate)
            {
                if (SelectedTags == null)
                {
                    blogsToUpdate.BlogTags = new List<BlogTag>();
                    return;
                }
                if (SelectedCategories == null)
                {
                    blogsToUpdate.BlogCategories = new List<BlogCategory>();
                    return;
                }

                var SelectedTagsHS = new HashSet<string>(SelectedTags);
                var SelectedCategoriesHS = new HashSet<string>(SelectedCategories);
                var blogTags = new HashSet<int>(blogsToUpdate.BlogTags.Select(c => c.BlogTagID));

                foreach (var tag in _RepositoryTag.Get())
                {
                    if (SelectedTagsHS.Contains(tag.BlogTagID.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (!blogTags.Contains(tag.BlogTagID))
                        {
                            blogsToUpdate.BlogTags.Add(tag);
                        }
                    }//if
                    else
                    {
                        if (blogTags.Contains(tag.BlogTagID))
                        {
                            blogsToUpdate.BlogTags.Remove(tag);
                        }
                    }//else
                }//foreach tag


                var blogcategories = new HashSet<int>
                   (blogsToUpdate.BlogCategories.Select(c => c.BlogCategoryID));
                foreach (var Category in _RepositoryCategory.Get())
                {
                    if (SelectedCategoriesHS.Contains(Category.BlogCategoryID.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (!blogcategories.Contains(Category.BlogCategoryID))
                        {
                            blogsToUpdate.BlogCategories.Add(Category);
                        }
                    }//if
                    else
                    {
                        if (blogcategories.Contains(Category.BlogCategoryID))
                        {
                            blogsToUpdate.BlogCategories.Remove(Category);
                        }
                    }//else
                }//foreach skill
            }
```

Comment: Where exatctly in your code the exception is thrown? This exception is thrown when you have objects tracked by different contexts, and you try to  use the object of a context via the other. For examples, if you have object A inserted in DB via context A, and then create object B using context B, and associate object A with object B, and call savechanges on either context, you will get the exception.

Comment: in insert i am getting error here this.context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
and update this line   dbSet.Attach(entity); , i need to mention i have 3 instance from 3 repository tag,category and blog but i cannot understand is the object i am filling it is valid and with out repository it si working 
any way do you have any suggestion how can i manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using multiple contexts to work with a single Entity.
On your controller constructor you have these lines:

```
this._Repository = new GenericRepository<Blog>(new DbContext());
this._RepositoryTag = new GenericRepository<BlogTag>(new DbContext());
this._RepositoryCategory = new GenericRepository<BlogCategory>(new DbContext());
```

Here, you are creating 3 repositories 9that are supposed to work together) with 3 different contexts.

After that, you proceed to read from the `RepositoryTag` repository, here:

```
var tagToAdd = _RepositoryTag.GetById(int.Parse(tag));
```

When you do this, the object `tagToAdd` becomes attached to the context inside `RepositoryTag`. If you debug your list `BlogTags` where you add this `tagToAdd` you will see that you have a dynamic proxy, which means that that objetc is attached to a context.

After that, you use another context to fill repository category, here:

```
var catToAdd = _RepositoryCategory.GetById(int.Parse(cat));
blog.BlogCategories.Add(catToAdd);
```

Now, your `blog` object has references to 2 different contexts: the one you used to load the tags (`RepositoryTag`), and the one you used to load the blog category (`RepositoryCategory`).

Finally, you try to inser the `blog` usgin a third context:

```
_Repository.Insert(blog);
```

This will throw an exception because EF can't work with multiple contexts like this.

To solve this problem, simply instantiate a context before the repositories, and pass it to all yout repositories, like this:

```
this.context = new DbContext(); // The context you need to use for all operations you are performing here.
this._Repository = new GenericRepository<Blog>(this.context);
this._RepositoryTag = new GenericRepository<BlogTag>(this.context);
this._RepositoryCategory = new GenericRepository<BlogCategory>(this.context);
```

Now, don't forget you should dispose your contexts. This is why the most recommended and common approach is to use a code like this:

```
using (var ctx = new DbContext()) {

    var repo = new GenericRepository<Blog>(ctx);
    var repoTag = new GenericRepository<BlogTag>(ctx);
    var repoCategory = new GenericRepository<BlogCategory>(ctx);

    <the rest of your code where you build the `blog` object>

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help ;) that is right it is working now ;)